# How to make a jumbotron the same width as a picture in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey guys and gals I'm new to using bootstrap and I am trying to do something pretty simple but it is escaping me currently. I am trying to make my jumbotron to be the same size as picture placed above it.

```
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <img src="img/NYC Skyline.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
              </div><!-- pic of NYC -->
           </div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="jumbotron" class="col-xs-12">
                 <h1>Welcome to Falke!</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-info">Get Started</a>
                 </div><!-- end of container for hero unit for blurb-->
              </div>
        </div>
```

The issue I'm having is that the jumbotron will stretch past the max width of the picture placed above it. How can I avoid this happening thanks. I am using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the jumbotron div in a column div, NOT add a column class to jumbotron. See the code below:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="jumbotron">
             <h1>Welcome to Falke!</h1>
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-info">Get Started</a>
        </div><!-- end of jumbotron-->
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: How would you make sure the jumbotron doesn't exceed the max size of the picture.

Comment: col-xs-12 will set the containing width and since you set that for the image (and used the class "img-responsive")as well as the jumbotron, you should be fine. Is that not happening?

Comment: Also you should make sure NYC Skyline.jpg is as least as wide as the largest container size (which is around 1170 pixels wide)

Comment: The picture is less the 1170 pixels wide so that might be the issue but the jumbotron is exceeding the max width of the picture.

Comment: Both jumbotron and your image are constrained by col-xs-12, which in turn is contained by the container. Any col-x-12 is full width. At some point once you go beyond the max-width of the image, the jumbotron is going to wider (as you have stated). There may be a way to write some javascript to have jumbotron match the current width of the image. Another option is to make the image a background image and use background-size: contain, thus the image will scale up to match its container size (this case col-xs-12).